# Twitter Box Embed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

For my website, I'm looking for a way to embed a Twitter box that shows only one update at a time: http://www.natashabedingfield.com/

I need it to look exactly like the aforementioned, except with different colours (I can modify those).

Can someone please show me how to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://search.twitter.com/api/. Use the API info and call it with any language.

Answer (score 1):

creds maker of jtwitter.
HTML part
http://pastebin.com/VHmZMNkZ

the jquery.jtwitter.min.js
http://pastebin.com/aT3CPCmL

The usage is

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.jTwitter('twitter account', 1, function(posts){ // Name,posts
  for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++){
     $('.posts').append(posts[i].text + " - Add on text");
     $('.twat').hide();
  }
});
</script>
```